# Netbeans "default config" for Maven projects

Tags: java, maven-2, netbeans, maven-3

I've got a Maven project under Netbeans that requires a non-default configuration because it is platform specific. If the user does not pick a configuration I have no way of knowing which platform to build for. I can't use profile activators because sometimes we build Windows binaries under a Linux box.

Is there a way to disable `<default config>` or fail a build with a descriptive error message if it's used or tell Netbeans that when someone builds `<default config>` it should really build config `windows-x86`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

default config just means no profiles activated. So your build would have to be capable of figuring out that no profile is activated (by whatever means, missing property, missing plugin config). maven enforcer plugin could do it maybe. 
There is no way in netbeans to do anything like that, you have to come up with a maven solution.